# Why do I receive null when i pass this id?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, ecmascript-6

```
import React from "react";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Pass: <input type="password" id="pass"/>
      <MailIcon onClick={showPass("pass")}/>
    </div>
  );
  function showPass(e)
  {
    console.log(e);
    var pass = document.getElementById(e);
    console.log(pass);
    if(pass.type === "password")
    {
      pass.type="text";
    }
    else
    {
      pass.type ="password";
    }
  }
}
```

**I am calling a simple function to change the type of the field to text but I don't know why it is showing me this error**

[Error-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBMW9.png)

[Console-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn0VE.png)

When I console log the e it shows the "pass" name but when i pass to getElementById it converts to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using native DOM methods [you need to start thinking in React, and use state](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). You can then click the icon to call a function to update the `type` state (initially set to 'password') which will be reflected in the new render.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise the state
  const  [type, setType] = useState('password');

  // Set the new state when the main icon is clicked
  function changeType() {
    const newType = type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    setType(newType);
  }

  // Capitalise the label
  function capitalise(str) {
    return `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.substr(1, str.length)}`;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {capitalise(type)}: <input type={type} />
      <button onClick={changeType}>Mail icon</button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Ok..noted will do the same changes

Answer (score 0):

Change `onClick={showPass("pass")}` to `onClick={()=>showPass("pass")}`

Comment: Ok thanks for the help will do the required changes!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple the mistake:

**1-** Don't use **getElementById** in the react.

**2-** You must use from **e.target** instead **e**, for referring to element.

**1,2 =>** **var pass = e.target;** .

**3-** Even so, in the your If, **pass.type** is null! because **MailIcon** not have a **type** attribute.(the input tag has a type attribute)

Answer (score -1):

You Just Need To Implement Function Like This :
`onClick={() => showPass("pass")}`